# Shikashi: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments with sandboxed code

Tags: ruby

I am having issue with Shikashi when invoking methods with more then one parameter:

```
class MyTest

    def self.think message
    end

    def self.say person,message
    end
end

include Shikashi

privileges = Privileges.new        
privileges.allow_const_read "MyTest"
privileges.object(MyTest).allow_all
privileges.instances_of(MyTest).allow_all  

Sandbox.new.run(privileges, "MyTest.think('you')")  

Sandbox.new.run(privileges, "MyTest.say('you', 'hi there')")
```

This one works

```
Sandbox.new.run(privileges, "MyTest.think('you')")
```

Here I am getting an ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

```
Sandbox.new.run(privileges, "MyTest.say('you', 'hi there')")
```

When I call it outside the Sandbox all is well.

Whats wrong? I am using  ruby-1.9.3-p194

Comment: without the sandbox and ruby 1.8.6 it works well for me http://codepad.org/eaPWM6pM so may is it a behavior of the ruby version so can you try an other ruby version? btw. here -> http://www.compileonline.com/execute_ruby_online.php with ruby 2.0.o it works also well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

The bug has been fixed in evalhook version 0.5.2; upgrade to that and all should be well.

**Original Answer:**

There's a bug in all versions of evalhook (what shikashi uses to eval the code) greater than 0.3.1 where methods are only called with the first argument.  For example:

```
Sandbox.new.run(privileges, "MyTest.think('you', 'hi there')")
```

works just fine, ignoring the second argument.

Unfortunately, the way the dependencies are set up, you'd need to downgrade to shikashi 0.3.1 to use evalhook 0.3.1, but at least for me, shikashi 0.3.1 is broken and fails to install.  I think your options are:

1. Don't use shikashi,
2. Don't use methods with more than one argument in the sandbox,
3. Track down and fix the bug in evalhook,
4. Get the developer to fix the bug, or
5. See if you can convince a newer version of shikashi to work with evalhook 0.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

I am the developer of shikashi and I just pushed the fixed version of evalhook gem (v0.5.2, dependency of shikashi). To update the gem:

```
gem update evalhook
```

And then it should work